# How do I get xid from pid (and vice versa)?

Tags: linux, pid, x11

How do I get the pid from the xid (X window identifier)? How do I get the list of xids for a given pid?

(Assuming all applications run with `DISPLAY=:0`, without network transparency being in use)

I'm expecting something like:

1. Dig in /proc/$pid/fd/ to track connection to X server
2. Follow that connection, dig in `` /proc/`pidof X`/fd ``
3. Dig inside X as it should know how to map connections to it to windows.

Comment: In general: Not at all. The reason is that the X-Window system is/supports inherently network connection (even if you dont use it). The only viable way I could think of, is your expected internal digging - which can be different from x-server to x-server.

Comment: X server is Xorg. I want solution than works in non-networked case. Isn't it obvious that it is possible for any gived system?

Comment: The "obvious" solution will involve ugly plumbing and duct tape since this isn't the way X was designed to work.

Comment: 1. How to do it? 2. How to make it less ugly? May be there's some convenient X extension for this?

Comment: I think it's highly unlikely that there is an X extension since it's designed from the bottom up to be network transparent and not tie up a "process" to an "X resource".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for my purposes:

```
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ XID=0x340001c
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ printf "%d\n" $XID               # Convert from hex to decimal
54525980
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ xdotool getwindowpid 54526066
20639
=^_^= izkata@Izein:~$ ps 20639
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
20639 ?        Ssl  116:25 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `xprop -id <windowid> _NET_WM_PID` to get the PID property of the window in question. You should know the window id of the window and not all applications set the `_NET_WM_PID` atom.

Comment: Few applications set pid properly, the applicatin in question (xbmc) does not.

Comment: How to find it out myself? How to track connection to X server, then xid's of that connection?

Comment: You can get the id using `xwininfo`. I'm not sure about programmatically.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim, I think it will work only if program voluntarily declares it's PID to X server. I need solution to actually find out PID.

Comment: If all the processes are `xbmc`, you should be getting the pid of the `xbmc` process from `/proc` or somewhere rather than trying to dig bag from the X window identifiers.

Comment: This is about getting xid of XBMC's window (in possible presence of other similar window)

Comment: What do you mean by "other similar windows"? If it's the XBMC windows you want to kill, find the process id of xbmc and send that a termination signal. Why bother with X at all?

Comment: Means 1. I want to find XBMC's window (without modifying XMBC's code), 2. Other applications can place windows with name and class just like XBMC's. And I prefer method that is not xbmc-specific, but will work for any X application.

Comment: So, what is wrong in just finding the pid of xbmc (or any other process that you're interested in) and killing it the old fashioned way? Why bother with X at all?

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim, Why killing? I haven't mentioned killing or closing things anywhere. I just need to reliably find it's window (and window of any other X application without classname and windowname) to do various things with the window.

Comment: Ah okay. I was misled into signals when you mentioned PIDs. The `xlsclients` program along with `-l` will give you a list of all X resources allocated to various commands. You will not get the pid but you will get the command name. Would that help you?

Answer (score 1):

wmctrl lists windows, their xids and optionally the pid of their process. So assuming there is only one window with your `$pid`, you could get the corresponding xid with

```sh
wmctrl -ulp | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f1,3 | grep $pid | cut -d" " -f1
```

and conversely, assuming the xid is in hexa,get the pid

```sh
wmctrl -ulp | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f1,3 | grep $xid | cut -d" " -f2
```

.

Comment: It works, but I assume it requires a window manager running.